# Okhttp java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

Tags: java, python, android, flask, okhttp

im currently working on Android aplication and im making a simple GET request using okttp3. Im using my flask aplication as the API endpoint.
**Code Android**:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {

                    String s = response.body().string();
                    System.out.println(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        });
```

**Code Flask**

```
@app.route('/abc', methods=["GET"])
def abc():
    return jsonify({"test": "abc"})
```

When i make the request using POSTMAN i have no issues:
[postman get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joNXe.png)
However when using the java code above sometimes it works, other times i get the following error

```
D/OkHttp: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:389)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.kt:276)
        at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.kt:1655)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readString(RealBufferedSource.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.kt:187)
        at com.example.teste.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:504)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have tried mutiple solutions that have been sugested at other posts like:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build();
```

or

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Connection","close")
                    .url(uri)
                    .build();
```

but none of them work. Whats the problem here? I have tried making requests with the same code with other dummy api and it always works. What is my flask api missing?

The error happens here:

```
val read = super.read(sink, minOf(bytesRemaining, byteCount))
      if (read == -1L) {
        connection.noNewExchanges() // The server didn't supply the promised content length.
        val e = ProtocolException("unexpected end of stream")
        responseBodyComplete()
        throw e
      }
```

It has something to do with the content lenght supplied by the server. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception was only happening when i use the emulator. On the device there was no problem.

Comment: That's not a clear answer. There's something wrong with OKHttp library. Actually what's happening that the java on emulator making request allot faster than predicted and as soon as it reads a bit of data into the buffer, the library just closes the connection leaving the rest of incoming data hanging in the middle of nowhere, whereas the server needs a bit more time to write the entire data into the output buffer. Now this would sometime works on emulator just like a false/positive result. Those who're familiar with C socket programming will be very much aware of this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

what about adding an interceptor for each request and add `Connection-Close` header? as below.

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Connection", "close").build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        })
        .build();
```

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the
>   response. For example,
>
> Connection: close in either the request or the response header
>   fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered
>   `persistent' (section 8.1) after the current request/response is
>   complete.
>
> HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections MUST
>   include the "close" connection option in every message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a proxy-server which does request body adjustments. So I changed body but forgot to adjust Content-Length=123 header and HTTPClient was getting this error. So it might mean inconsistency between this header and actual body length.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my use case, I was downloading a large file from an nginx powered server, and processing the data on the fly. To do that, I read small bits of data from the inputstream corresponding to what is currently being processed, and took my time processing before consuming more data. Somehow, the system (or maybe OkHttp), cached a large piece of the file ahead of time, and wouldn't contact the server for more unless I consumed this cache. This was  evident because even after turning the server off, the program would be able to continue reading and processing for a few minutes before the unexpected end of stream is reached.

Turns out, nginx is configured to [drop the connection if the client didn't contact the server for 60s by default](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#send_timeout):

> ```
> Syntax:   send_timeout time;  
> Default:  send_timeout 60s;  
> Context:  http, server, location
> ```
>
> Sets a timeout for transmitting a response to the client. The timeout is set only between two successive write operations, not for the transmission of the whole response. If the client does not receive anything within this time, the connection is closed.

So, the dilly-dallying while consuming the data caused the issue. I solved the issue by increasing the timeout in my server configuration:

```
location /MyLargeDownloadsFolder/ {
   send_timeout 600s;
}
```